# How do I add a “fit” class on the last <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I'm trying to add a "fit" class to the last  using the follosing snippet but no luck:

```
$(".col-514:last").addClass("fit");
```

The html code I have is:

```
<div>

    <div class="grid col-514">
        Related post1
    </div>

    <div class="col-514">
        Related post2
    </div>

</div>
```

The desired code should be as follow:

```
    <div class="grid col-514">
        Related post1
    </div>

    <div class="col-514 fit">
        Related post2
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can’t simply use `:last-child` in your CSS in the first place …?

Comment: The code provided does work. http://fiddle.jshell.net/44fQF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".col-514").last().addClass("fit");
```

http://api.jquery.com/last/